# Keyboard shortcut to allow greek characters

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

What keyboard shortcut allows greek characters to be typed when pressing the letter keys?

I was trying to remember a particular shortcut involving the alt button and was trying various key combinations. But then when I started typing again it, Greek characters appeared.

I am interested in how I made this happen. I've been trying to replicate it again. But to no avail.

(I was using Visual Studio at the time, but I suspect that it would have been the same in any text editor, such as MS-word.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install the Geek Language from control panel.
2. Use Alt-Shift to switch between your installed languages.

This is global for all applications in the system

Comment: Thank you. So simple but so right.